# HTML - Override style for one <li> element in my menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following classes in my css file

```
  #megamenu {
    /*styling here*/
  }

  #megamenu li {
    /*styling here*/
  }

  #megamenu li:hover {
    /*styling here*/
  }
```

In my HTML I have

```
   <ul id="megamenu">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
```

Naturally all of the li elements get the hover applied to them.  How can I turn off the hover for only Item 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Css will overwrite all styles from the top to the bottom of your definition

```css
 #megamenu {
    /*styling here*/
  }

  #megamenu li {
    /*styling here*/
  }

  #megamenu li:hover {
    color: green
  }
  #megamenu li:nth-child(3):hover {
    color: yellow
  }
```

```html
<ul id="megamenu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
  #megamenu li:nth-child(3):hover {
    /*styling here*/
  }
```

Here is a full demo

```css
 #megamenu {
    /*styling here*/
  }

  #megamenu li {
    /*styling here*/
  }

  #megamenu li:hover {
    color: blue
  }

  #megamenu li:nth-child(3):hover {
    color: red
  }
```

```html
<ul id="megamenu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you only have 3 elements you can use [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
     #megamenu {
        /*styling here*/
      }

      #megamenu li {
        /*styling here*/
      }

      #megamenu li:hover {
        color: blue
      }

      #megamenu li:last-child:hover {
        color: red
      }
```

```html
<ul id="megamenu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add like this:

```
 #megamenu {
  list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
  }

  #megamenu li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #megamenu li:not(:last-child):hover {
   color:red;
  }
```

Working Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Lgkf75jb/

Alternative, For a particular li you can add the class and give like this,

HTML code:

```
<ul id="megamenu">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li class="no_effects">Item 3</li>
   </ul>
```

CSS Style:

```
 #megamenu {
  list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
  }

  #megamenu li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #megamenu li:not(.no_effects):hover {
   color:red;
  }
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Lgkf75jb/1/